# Is $\langle S \rangle$ the largest subgroup $D$ such that, if any two homomorphisms $p, q$ agree on $S$, they also agree on $D$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a question about exercise 2.1 in [Bergman's companion to Lang's *Algebra*](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/.C.to.L/).

Let $G$ be a group, $S$ any subset of $G$, and $\langle S\rangle$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$.  Define a set $D \subseteq G$ by:

$x \in D \iff$ for any group $H$ and any two homomorphisms $p, q: G \to H$, if $p|_S = q|_S$, then $p(x) = q(x)$.

Given this definition, it's not difficult to see that $D$ is a group, so that $\langle S \rangle \leq D$. Bergman's question is: must $D = \langle S \rangle$?

It seems to me that the answer is affirmative, or at least affirmative under certain natural conditions, because the only way for $x$ to belong to $D$ and not to $\langle S \rangle$ is if $x$ is "accidentally" determined by $S$. But I can't see how to even begin the proof. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's worth knowing that the analogous statement for rings is false. So however you prove this fact it has to involve something true for groups but not rings.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - That's interesting. Can you give me a specific counter-example for the ring-theoretic case?

Comment: How about this for a counter-example: $G=Q_8$ and $S=\{1\}$? (I think, in this case, $D=\langle -1\rangle$.)

Comment: (Actually, if this works, a simpler example with the same idea is to take $G$ cyclic of order $4$, and $S$ trivial.)

Comment: I think the answer is yes, $D = \langle S \rangle$. Consider the free product of two copies of $G$ amalgamated at $\langle S \rangle$.

Comment: @verret - I don't think that works. Take the direct product of $G$ with itself. Then there are two homomorphisms $p: x \mapsto (e, x)$, $q: x \mapsto (x, e)$ which agree on the trivial group but disagree on all the rest. So the trivial group can't be a counterexample.

Comment: Right, I think I was assuming the homomorphisms were surjective.

Comment: Derek's comment answers the question (using the same idea as in your last comment).

Comment: @DerekHolt - I think verret is right that this answers my question. If you want, you can post it as an answer. I don't know much about free products, so you can include a bit more detail in the answer, if you want.

Comment: Derek's answer isn't yet complete. You can perform the same construction on rings, and it doesn't answer your question, because there's an important fact about free product of groups that isn't true for rings.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - Hmm, is this related to the fact that the free product of rings can collapse to the trivial ring, whereas that's not a possibility for groups (as far as I know)?